# ¿Como hacer que las tablas de 'treeview' varien y me muestren los datos dependiendo de lo que ingrese?

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, tablas

Veran, estoy trabajando en un programa para gestionar datos, y me he encontrado con un problema que me esta haciendo doler la cabeza. Tengo una pestaña donde hay varios botones y cada boton me abre una ventana donde me muestra en una pestaña la planilla completa de todos los datos ingresados en mysql, en la segunda necesito que se muestren solo los que correspondan a una fecha que ingrese, los siguientes a un nombre que ingrese y asi. El problema surge porque cuando le doy a buscar por fecha no me muestra nada, y la tabla se me duplica, aca dejo el codigo para que lo vean y si pueden me orienten un poco. Gracias.

```
class Table(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent=None, title="", headers=[], height=20, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self._title = tk.Label(self, text=title, background="#F7F2E0",height=2, pady=5)
    self._headers = headers
    self._tree = ttk.Treeview(self,
                              height=height,
                              columns=self._headers, 
                              show="headings")
    self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

    # Agregamos dos scrollbars 
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
    vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview)
    hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

    self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    self._tree.pack(side="left")

    for header in self._headers:
        self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
        self._tree.column(header, stretch=True,
                          width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))

def add_row(self, row):
    self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
    for i, item in enumerate(row):
        col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
        if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)

def consulta():

conn = pymysql.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="",
database="DBDistribuidora")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Fecha, Codigo, Nombre, Marca, Cantidad, Precio FROM entrada_consignacion")
return cursor
conn.close()


def entrada_reporte():

t3 = tk.Toplevel()#ventana principal
t3.title("INVENTARIO")
t3.geometry('530x650')
t3.resizable(False,False)
t3.focus_set()
t3.grab_set()

#Creamos el contenedor de las pasteñas dentro de esa ventana principal
notebook = ttk.Notebook(t3)
#Hacemos que se expanda hacia ambos lados
notebook.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
#Definimos los nombres de las pestañas y las agregamos al contenedor de pestañas
Planilla_Completa = ttk.Frame(notebook)
Fecha = ttk.Frame(notebook)
Codigo = ttk.Frame(notebook)
Nombre = ttk.Frame(notebook)
Marca = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(Planilla_Completa, text='PLANILLAS COMPLETAS')
notebook.add(Fecha, text='FECHA')
notebook.add(Codigo, text='CODIGO')
notebook.add(Nombre, text='NOMBRE')
notebook.add(Marca, text='MARCA')

clientes_headers = ("Fecha", "Codigo", "Nombre","Marca","Cantidad","Precio")
clientes_tab = Table(Planilla_Completa, title="ENTRADAS DE MERCADERIAS", headers=clientes_headers)
clientes_tab.pack()
try:
    cursor = consulta()#aquí tare el resultado de la consulta a la BD
    #Aquí carga la tabla
    for row in cursor:
        clientes_tab.add_row(row)
except:
    messagebox.showwarning("CUIDADO","HAY CELDAS VACIAS")


#---Definimos la funcion para buscar por "FECHA"---


#--Definimos las cajas para ingresare texto de cada pestaña--

LBfecha = tk.Label(Fecha, text="Ingrese la Fecha que desea buscar : ")
LBfecha.place(x=160, y=490)
fecha = tk.StringVar()
entry_fecha = tk.Entry(Fecha, textvariable=fecha, justify="center")
entry_fecha.place(x=180, y=520, height=25)
entry_fecha.focus()

 #--Definimos los Botones de cada pestaña y los de salir y volver--

BTfecha = tk.Button(Fecha, text="BUSCAR")
BTfecha.pack()
BTfecha.place(x=110, y=550, width=300, height=30)

volver = tk.Button(t3, text="ATRAS", command=t3.destroy)
volver.pack()
volver.place(x=10, y=580)
#--Definimos una funcion para cerrar el programa completo-- 
try:
    def cerrar_todo():
        ventana.destroy() and ventana_reposicion.destroy() and t3.destroy()

    salir = tk.Button(t3, text="SALIR", command=cerrar_todo)
    salir.pack()
    salir.place(x=480, y=580)
except:
    pass
```

Demas esta decir, que lo que he intentado no esta aca, porque no me funciono. Quiero saber desde ahi que puedo hacer o como puedo hacer con un ejemplo, para que al ir a la pestaña "Fecha" yo ingrese una fecha en el 'tk.Entry' y al darle al boton "Buscar"(previamente definido el 'command=') me devuelva en la misma tabla ya creada solo los valores correspondientes a la fecha ingresada o sea me devuelva("SELECT * FROM entrada_consignacion WHERE Fecha='%s'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar, era muy sencillo, simplemente, tenia que definir en la pestaña "fecha" la tabla creada y gestionar una nueva consulta, algo asi:

```
 #---Definimos la funcion para buscar por "FECHA"---
def fecha0():
    fech = entry_fecha.get()
    conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="DBDistribuidora")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Fecha, Codigo, Nombre, Marca, Cantidad, Precio FROM entrada_consignacion WHERE Fecha = '"+fech+"'")
    return cursor
    conn.close()

def fecha_reporte():
    f = tk.Toplevel()#ventana principal
    f.title("INVENTARIO")
    f.geometry('530x650')
    f.resizable(False,False)
    f.focus_set()
    f.grab_set()
    clientes_headers1 = ("Fecha", "Codigo", "Nombre","Marca","Cantidad","Precio")
    clientes_tab1 = Table(f, title="FECHA", headers=clientes_headers1)
    clientes_tab1.pack()

    cursor = fecha0()

    for row in cursor:
        clientes_tab1.add_row(row)

#--Definimos los Botones de cada pestaña y los de salir y volver--        
entry_fecha = tk.StringVar()
fechatx = tk.Entry(t3, textvariable=entry_fecha)
fechatx.place(x=110, y=480, width=300, height=30)
BTfecha = tk.Button(t3, text="BUSCAR",command=fecha_reporte)
BTfecha.pack()
BTfecha.place(x=110, y=550, width=300, height=30)
volver = tk.Button(t3, text="ATRAS", command=t3.destroy)
volver.pack()
volver.place(x=10, y=580)
#--Definimos una funcion para cerrar el programa completo-- 
try:
    def cerrar_todo():
        ventana.destroy() and ventana_reposicion.destroy() and t3.destroy()

    salir = tk.Button(t3, text="SALIR", command=cerrar_todo)
    salir.pack()
    salir.place(x=480, y=580)
except:
    pass
```